# How to stop player from automatically jumping on a moving platform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a moving platform that goes vertically top to bottom and then bottom to top and so on. Platform moves fine but placing my player on it makes my player unstable.

When platform moves from top to bottom, my player kinda bounces on it. When platform moves from bottom to top, it remain stable on the way but when it reaches top point, my player makes a jump by itself.

Its get even worse when i increase the speed of my platform. I don't know if its due to unity 2d physics effect or what. I have tried to use physics material 2D on my player object and platform by setting bounce to 0 and friction to 50 but nothing seems to work. Any one have idea how to disable physics effect of moving platform? Following is my code for moving platform:

```
public class BrickMoveVErtical : MonoBehaviour {
     public Vector3 positionOne;
     public Vector3 positiontwo;
     public Vector3 nextposition;
    /*Empty object is already made on unity editor and its parent of platform(Plank) and other  
       empty object "pointB". Point "B" is already mapped on editor and platform is set to go from 
         its original pos to point B */
     public Transform plankTranform;         
     public Transform positionBTransform;
     public float speed;
     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         positionOne = plankTranform.localPosition;
         positiontwo = positionBTransform.localPosition;
         nextposition = positiontwo;
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         move();
             }
     private void move() {
    plankTranform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(plankTranform.localPosition,nextposition,Time.deltaTime*speed);
         if(Vector3.Distance(plankTranform.localPosition,nextposition)<0.1)
         { changeMovementPlank(); }
     }
     void changeMovementPlank() {
         nextposition = nextposition != positionOne ? positionOne : positiontwo;
     }                        

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with fast platforms in my game, the character would be left out in the air or slide off, depending on the direction of the platform.
I found a workaround for the problem by simply changing the character `transform.parent` to the platform it was jumping on, whenever the player exists the platform collider, simply return the players original `transform.parent`.

Note that this might cause other bugs or problems that will need to optimize, depending on your game that is.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me but i had one small problem. Making player child of platform by using `transform.parent` makes my player shrinks in scale with respect to platform. Is there way to just use parent tranform's position property without have to worry about scale?

Comment: I don't have my unity installed atm, but if I had to guess, probably changing the local scale of the character once it hits would solve it. You can do this with simple multiplication using the local scale of your platform.

Comment: @EslaBaeny you can also use an empty game object with scale of 1 as the container of the platform in which the actual scaled platform exists. now changing the parent to the empty container shouldn't affect the scale of the player

Comment: Does the same issue happen if you use the SetParent function on the transform?

Comment: @Bijan so i made gameobject child of platform and set its scale to 1 and made player child of gameobj 'other.transform.SetParent(gameobjTransform);' but that doesnt work as well.  player is shrinking with respect to platform not w.r.t new gameobj

Comment: @EslaBaeny, I am guessing the problem with scaling is due to player's game object tree and not the platform's.

Comment: @Bijan any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: @EslaBaeny, I advise you to search for `scale` in your project and see where you are changing the transform scale. this is common mistake for game developers. always use scale = 1 for important objects such as player, object pools, level blocks, platforms, etc. and use scaled objects only inside them

Comment: To solve this (at least this worked for me), wrap your character in another empty game object as a container, this way, the container scales will change but the character won't (unless you are changing the local scale of the platform in-game).
pretty much as Bijan suggested but do it for the character instead of each platform.

Comment: @BsharaZahran setting container on top of player doesn't work for me, That made moving platform unstable for my player again. I guess i am stuck in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to set/unset the parent of a GameObject:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "PlatformGroup")
        player.SetParent(other.gameObject.transform)

}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "PlatformGroup")
         player.SetParent(null);
}
```

What you should do is:

1. Create an empty GameObject, and you make your platform child of this
   empty GameObject. Tag it as `PlatformGroup`.
2. You add the script to move the platform to this EmptyGame Object,
   instead of using it in the platform itself.
3. Then add a collider to empty gameobject(`PlatformGroup`) and another to the Player. Set the one of the player as trigger.
4. Add the code above to your player controller.

Now, when the Player jumps over the Platform if will become a child of the same GameObject of the platform and they will move together without any deformations in the GameObject. Also when the player leaves the platform, walking or jumping out of it, it will stop being child.

Comment: I am gonna have to try this, I recently ran into the same issue OP is talking about and I fixed it with a... Funky way that I didn't like.

Comment: That doesnt work for me but i solved the problem with making `other.transform.SetParent(plankTranform);` inside my platform script. Now my player is stable on platform making plankTransform  parent of my player tranform property kinda messes up with scale of my player aslo. My player some times shrinks while standing on platform.

Comment: @EslaBaeny My approach works without changing the shape of the player or platform. But in your case the trigger is in the platform, not in the player. Also this approach takes into account that eventually the player will leave the platform

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre I tired this code that doesnt work. when Player jumps over the Platform its become a child of the of the platform container and NOT actual platform. In that way player position doesnt change w.r.t container platform. Container is still and player is going down with platform itself making the player bounce over it and make unstable for player. One way to solve is to make actual moving platform parent of player inside of container that solves problem but that lead player to shrink in scale because of using  'other.transform.SetParent(plankTranform)' on player